Decode the music puzzle
You don’t need an instrument to solve this, although basic music reading knowledge is required.
The answer is a thematic word.
Z
N
J
P
M
O
U
Y
K
T
R
E
S
A
F
T
I
N
L
N
T
(Attribution: I created this riddle.)
Hint:

The names of the notes do not spell out the word.

Hint 2:

Sharps, flats, and naturals are key to the puzzle.


Welcome to PSE! So the melody isn’t significant is that what you are saying?

@PDT, yes, the melody isn’t important. It’s actually kind of a terrible melody, because I had to mangle it to make it work for the puzzle. Oh well :)

Welcome, and a nice puzzle! It reminds me of a similar puzzle I once made :)

The answer is:

 INSTRUMENTAL

I noticed that

 Seven musical notes are used (a-g) and three modifiers (flat, none and sharp). The given table is 7x3 so let's use that as a lookup table like this:




 The given notes are: f (I), g (N), e-flat (S), g-sharp (T), d (R), c-flat (U), b (M), d-sharp (E), a (N), d-flat (T), e (A), g-flat (L).


Congratulations, you got it! Out of curiosity, how long did it take you/which hints did you need?

@ZonaC - what was the point of F# key signature if it isn't used in the solution? A red herring?

@ZonaC I got it quite quickly but I think I was lucky to immediately try something that turned out to be the right solution path. The link between 7 notes, 3 modifiers and the dimensions of the letter table was the breakthrough for me. Then it was just trying a few combinations...

@webadventurer, The F# key signature was left over from an earlier version of the puzzle, and I forgot to delete it. Unintentional red herring :)
